# Knockout-2.2.0.Debug.js throwing error in IE9 "SCRIPT3: Member not found." while sorting

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-sortable

I have my application with MVC4/Knockout.js. I am not able to get why i am getting error in IE9. Error details are as below:-

> SCRIPT3: Member not found.   knockout-2.2.0.debug.js, line 1068
>   character 13

`Screenshot` is as below:

[image: IE9 Error screenshot]

I am not even including `knockout-2.2.0.debug.js`

Thanks for your time and your help.

@Sivanv

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce in a jsFiddle. I know that it can be tough in a situation like this one.

Comment: What versions of jQuery + jQuery UI are you using?

Comment: i am using Jquery1.7, knockout 2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [RP Niemeyer's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594420/rp-niemeyer) solution, it worked for me.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.uiSortableList = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccesor, context) {
            var $element = $(element),
                list = valueAccessor();

            $element.sortable({
                containment: 'parent',
                placeholder: 'placeholder',
                update: function (event, ui) {
                    var item = ko.dataFor(ui.item[0]),
                        newIndex = ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(ui.item.parent().children(), ui.item[0]);
                    if (newIndex >= list().length) newIndex = list().length - 1;
                    if (newIndex < 0) newIndex = 0;

                    ui.item.remove();
                    list.remove(item);
                    list.splice(newIndex, 0, item);
                }
            });
        }
};

var ViewModel = function (items) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);

    this.data = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.toJSON(this.items());
    }, this);
};

    var vm = new ViewModel([ { name : 'foo' }, { name : 'bar' }, { name : 'baz' }]);

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/KrGY8/) link